# Google combo chart with multiple bars and lines

Tags: charts, google-visualization

See this image I am showing some data I have to compare each bar with data shown by line graph:

[image: google combo chart bar + line graph]

Is this possible in Google combo chart?

Comment: Please embed your image into the post. For your actual problem, what have you tried so far? What output are you getting?

Comment: I can't embed image because I have low reputation.

Comment: I want to compare these bars with some other values, in the form of line graph. Suppose red - shows wrong questions, green - shows correct questions and grey - shows skipped questions for some student now I have to compare it with toppers behaviour. I can do this with different lines in google charts, but according to design I have to do it with single line. Is it possible.

Answer (score 3):

sure it's possible, see following example...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Month', 'Bolivia', 'Ecuador', 'Madagascar', 'Papua New Guinea', 'Rwanda', 'Average'],
      ['2004/05',  165,      938,         522,             998,           450,      614.6],
      ['2005/06',  135,      1120,        599,             1268,          288,      682],
      ['2006/07',  157,      1167,        587,             807,           397,      623],
      ['2007/08',  139,      1110,        615,             968,           215,      609.4],
      ['2008/09',  136,      691,         629,             1026,          366,      569.6]
    ]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {
      title : 'Monthly Coffee Production by Country',
      vAxis: {title: 'Cups'},
      hAxis: {title: 'Month'},
      height: 420,
      orientation: 'vertical',
      seriesType: 'bars',
      series: {
        5: {
          pointSize: 5,
          type: 'line'
        }
      }
    });
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: line should touch each bar in each section, for comparison, see diagram again , thank for rply.

Answer (score 0):

Google Charts API provides a javascript wrapper that allows you to customize your combo chart . It has lot of configuration options , you can check them here [Google Combo Chart Config options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart#data-format) . You can use annotations options to build the lines across your bars .For full combo chart documentation vist here https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart